# How to call mongodb model inside serverless function using aws lambda

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

```
admin.auth().createUser({
  email,
  password,
  displayName: name
}).then((userRecord) => {
const userId = userRecord.uid;
console.log('userId', userId);
const uModel = new UserModel({
  _id: userId,
  address,
  nic,
  status
});
uModel.save();
const response = {
  statusCode: 200,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    message: 'Invoke',
    response: userId
  })
};
callback(null, response);
}).catch(error => error);
```

After the Firebase authentication, I want to save some data on MongoDB by using newly created user id in Firebase. When the code is executing it creates a new user in Firebase and doesn't save the data in the MongoDB.

Comment: I see `UserModel` there and the naming suggests this might be what you are talking about and that you are possibly using mongoose? If so then that `.save()` is actually an "async" call, which is not awaiting resolution via callback or promise. Also "mixing" callbacks and promises like the above appears to be doing is never a really good idea, and most notably for any possible errors are presently not routed to the callback. Wherever that is meant to go that is, because you did not include the full context of code in your question.

Comment: in here I m trying to save some fields to the user schema located in mongoDB after firebase user is returned.Now the problem is Firebase user is creating and code dosent runs after const uModel = new UserModel({